# Conditionally change values in some rows using existing factor levels, possibly in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am building a dataset.

I want to initiate it with one of the columns being a factor variable that contains the set of levels that this variable can take. Then I want to progressively edit this column as I apply rules building the dataset.

A toy example dataset:

```
mammals <- tibble(animal_name = c("Inapplicable",
                                  "Don't know",
                                  "Cat",
                                  "Dog",
                                  "Shark",
                                  "Wolf",
                                  "Pig"),
                  match_status = factor("not matched yet",
                                        levels = c("matched",
                                                   "not matched yet",
                                                   "unmatchable")),
                  match_reason = NA_character_)

table(mammals$match_status)
```

Now I try to start applying some conditions to change the values of the `match_status` variable. This does not work:

```
mammals <- mammals %>%
  mutate(
    match_status = case_when(
      animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know") ~ "unmatchable",
      animal_name == "Shark"                           ~ "unmatchable",
      animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf")                ~ "matched",
      TRUE                                             ~ match_status
    ),
    match_reason = case_when(
      animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know") ~ "No animal specified",
      animal_name == "Shark"                           ~ "Not a mammal",
      animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf")                ~ "In list of canines",
      TRUE                                             ~ match_reason
    )
  )
```

I have tried wrapping a `as.factor()` around the `case_when()`, but that also doesn't run.

If I comment out the first half (`match_status =`) of the `mutate()`, leaving only the `match_reason =` part, this works.

I think I could get a version running that converts the factor levels into character values, applies the conditional alterations I want on the variable and then as a separate stage converts it back into a factor, but I've steered clear of that as it seems more fragile. My reason for setting the factor levels up front was to constrain the legal values for the variable.

This works, using the base function `replace()`, but requires a fair bit more duplicate code and doesn't seem a very natural way of doing it in dplyr:

```
mammals <- mammals %>%
  mutate(
    match_status = replace(match_status, 
                           animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know"),
                           "unmatchable"),
    match_status = replace(match_status, 
                           animal_name == "Shark",
                           "unmatchable"),
    match_status = replace(match_status, 
                           animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf"),
                           "matched"),
    match_reason = case_when(
      animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know") ~ "No animal specified",
      animal_name == "Shark"                           ~ "Not a mammal",
      animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf")                ~ "In list of canines",
      TRUE                                             ~ match_reason
    )
  )
```

Bonus marks for approaches that let me update two variables simultaneously on the basis of the same criterion (e.g., in pseudocode `if animal_name == "Shark" then set match_status = "unmatchable" and set match_reason = "Not a mammal"`).

I've been trying to find a paradigmatic approach to this in dplyr, but am open to clean approaches that use base R too, I guess. I'd probably prefer something that works in a magrittr pipeline, but even that's not a dealbreaker.

Comment: Have a look at `case_when`, which should simply some of your code.

Comment: @mhovd The examples use `case_when` for the `match_reason` variable in both cases, and it works. If there's a way of constructing a compact `case_when` variant that works for the factor variable (`match_status`) then that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**For your original code**

It works if you wrap "unmatchable" in factor and indicate the appropriate levels.

```
mammals <- mammals %>%
  mutate(
    match_status = case_when(
      animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know") ~ factor("unmatchable", levels = c("matched",
                                                                                          "not matched yet",
                                                                                          "unmatchable")),
      animal_name == "Shark"                           ~ factor("unmatchable", levels = c("matched",
                                                                                          "not matched yet",
                                                                                          "unmatchable")),
      animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf")                ~ factor("matched", levels = c("matched",
                                                                                          "not matched yet",
                                                                                          "unmatchable")),
      TRUE                                             ~ match_status
    ),
    match_reason = case_when(
      animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know") ~ "No animal specified",
      animal_name == "Shark"                           ~ "Not a mammal",
      animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf")                ~ "In list of canines",
      TRUE                                             ~ match_reason
    )
  )
```

**Alternative**

Encode the match status and match reason in one string and then separate it later.

```
mammals <- mammals %>%
  mutate(match_info = case_when(animal_name=="Shark" ~ "unmatchable/Not a mammal",
                                animal_name %in% c("Inapplicable", "Don't know") ~ "unmatchable/No animal specified",
                                animal_name %in% c("Dog", "Wolf") ~ "matched/In list of canines",
                                TRUE ~ "not matched yet/")) %>%
  separate(match_info, into=c("match_status", "match_reason"), sep="/") %>%
  mutate(match_status, match_status=factor(match_status, levels=c("matched",
                                                     "not matched yet",
                                                     "unmatchable")))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  animal_name  match_status    match_reason         
  <chr>        <fct>           <chr>                
1 Inapplicable unmatchable     "No animal specified"
2 Don't know   unmatchable     "No animal specified"
3 Cat          not matched yet ""                   
4 Dog          matched         "In list of canines" 
5 Shark        unmatchable     "Not a mammal"       
6 Wolf         matched         "In list of canines" 
7 Pig          not matched yet ""
```

Comment: Thanks. The use of `factor()` for each of the assignments gives me a similar feeling to the `replace()` version I showed — it seems like a lot of boilerplate / repetition when it feels like there ought to be a compact way of re-setting a factor value to one of the other existing levels of the factor.

Comment: In my case, where there is a small number of factor levels, it's feasible to lessen the repetition by defining each of them as a variable that can then be referenced in the `mutate()` when needed. Like: 
`matched_f <- factor("matched", levels = c("matched", "unmatched", "unmatchable"))`

Comment: That is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my intended outcome here in the end by using the `dplyr::rows_update()` function (which as of May 2021 is 'lifecycle: experimental'), combined with defining each of the factor levels as its own variable.

First I set up the factor variables:

```
matched_f     <- factor("matched",
                        levels = c("matched",
                                   "not matched yet",
                                   "unmatchable"))
unmatched_f   <- factor("not matched yet",
                        levels = c("matched",
                                   "not matched yet",
                                   "unmatchable"))
unmatchable_f <- factor("unmatchable",
                        levels = c("matched",
                                   "not matched yet",
                                   "unmatchable"))
```

Then I use `dplyr::rows_update()` repeatedly to match the various criteria.

```
mammals <- mammals %>%
  rows_update(
    tibble(animal_name = c("Inapplicable",
                           "Don't know"),
           match_status = unmatchable_f,
           match_reason = "No animal specified"),
    by = "animal_name"
  ) %>%
  rows_update(
    tibble(animal_name = "Shark",
           match_status = unmatchable_f,
           match_reason = "Not a mammal"),
    by = "animal_name"
  ) %>%
  rows_update(
    tibble(animal_name = c("Dog", "Wolf"),
           match_status = matched_f,
           match_reason = "In list of canines"),
    by = "animal_name"
  )
```

This gives the expected results:

```
> table(mammals$match_status)

        matched not matched yet     unmatchable 
              2               2               3
```

```
> mammals
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  animal_name  match_status    match_reason       
  <chr>        <fct>           <chr>              
1 Inapplicable unmatchable     No animal specified
2 Don't know   unmatchable     No animal specified
3 Cat          not matched yet NA                 
4 Dog          matched         In list of canines 
5 Shark        unmatchable     Not a mammal       
6 Wolf         matched         In list of canines 
7 Pig          not matched yet NA
```

It would be also possible to do all of this in a single `rows_update()` call, setting each of the rows in the lookup table with its relevant values.

```
mammals <- mammals %>%
  rows_update(
    tribble(~animal_name,    ~match_status,   ~match_reason,
            "Inapplicable",  unmatchable_f,   "No animal specified",
            "Don't know",    unmatchable_f,   "No animal specified",
            "Shark",         unmatchable_f,   "Not a mammal",
            "Dog",           matched_f,       "In list of canines",
            "Wolf",          matched_f,       "In list of canines"),
    by = "animal_name"
  )
```

That's fine where the lists are short, as in the toy example. But in my real dataset, some of the vectors of strings that were being matched had a lot more elements, so there would have been lots of rows with duplicated `match_status` and `match_reason` values.